# How can I extract cellulose in plants using acids?

Tags: materials, carbohydrates, nanotechnology

Me and my classmates are doing a research project about the extraction of nano cellulose from plants to form a biocomposite, which can be a material to form an effective biodegradable material. We've done a quick research about it and most of the articles that we came across is to conduct an acid hydrolysis on the plant that we opt to use. We are kinda lost and confused as to what step or procedure we need to follow. Some articles also suggested that we can just boil the sample to extract the nano cellulose. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanocellulose#Manufacture I'm not sure that "extraction" can be done with acids only.

Comment: Thank you, @andselisk. What steps do you suggest to fully isolate and extract the cellulose?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot answer this question, not really my field. That was just a comment based on common Wikipedia info.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Renewable biological systems for alternative sustainable energy production](http://www.fao.org/docrep/W7241E/W7241E00.htm) (FAO, 1997). Chapter 3 is on cellulosic biomass.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, thank you for the info. My team will look into that